# Syntax error at beginning of command when running script

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash, shell, syntax-error

I am trying to run a script with ./insert_data.sh; and I get an error saying there is a syntax error at or near the "."
Am working in PSQL, thanks

Edit #1: My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to insert data from courses.csv and students.csv into students database

PSQL="psql -X --username=freecodecamp --dbname=students --no-align --tuples-only -c"

cat courses_test.csv | while IFS="," read MAJOR COURSE
do
  # get major_id
  MAJOR_ID=$($PSQL "SELECT major_id FROM majors WHERE major='$MAJOR'")

  # if not found
  if [[ -z $MAJOR_ID ]]
  then
    # insert major
    INSERT_MAJOR_RESULT=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO majors(major) VALUES('$MAJOR')")
    echo $INSERT_MAJOR_RESULT

    # get new major_id

  fi

  # get course_id

  # if not found

  # insert course

  # get new course_id

  # insert into majors_courses

done
```

Edit #2:  Command i'm using to run the script: ./insert_data.sh; Error I'm recieving:

```
   students=> ./insert_data.sh;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ./insert_data.sh;
        ^
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248277/discussion-on-question-by-a-s-syntax-error-at-beginning-of-command-when-runnin).

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem- I had to get out of the PSQL terminal and enter the command within the "project" directory

Answer (score 0):

We can't replicate your case 1:1 because lack of data. But you can always use bash debug with **-x flag** to see where it actually stuck:

```
test@test:/tmp$ bash -x ./test.sh
+ PSQL='psql -X --username=freecodecamp --dbname=students --no-align --tuples-only -c'
+ cat courses_test.csv
+ IFS=,
+ read MAJOR COURSE
++ psql -X --username=freecodecamp --dbname=students --no-align --tuples-only -c 'SELECT major_id FROM majors WHERE major='\''"Sex"'\'''
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```